# Serilog Setup with Two stage in .NET 6 RC1 using Minimal API

Tags: serilog

I could not find any example of using serilog configuration with Two stage setup in .NET 6 RC1 with minimal API

Comment: I've published a complete example using two-state initialization here: https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example (working project and explanatory README).

Answer (score 1):

Just use this line :

```
builder.WebHost.UseSerilog();
```

Sample Code :

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
          .WriteTo.Console()
          .CreateLogger();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DapperService>();
builder.WebHost.UseSerilog(); // <===============

// Build configuration
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
    .Build();


// Add access to generic IConfigurationRoot
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configuration);

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: Hi! `builder.WebHost` is an older API; `builder.Host` is the more recent and better-supported place to call `UseSerilog()`. The OP is looking for two-stage initialization, though, which requires `CreateBootstrapLogger()`; the all-important call is [this one](https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example/blob/dev/Program.cs#L5)

Answer (score 1):

`builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc .WriteTo.Console() .WriteTo.File("Your File Path"));`